# Is there a reason to retain .cmo or only .cma?

Tags: ocaml

Say, I have `mylibrary.ml` which provides wrappings to `library.c` and I want to bytecode-compile and provide `mylibrary.ml` as a library for other ocaml code. Compiling this to bytecode (and I am not considering compiling ocaml to native code here) produces a number of files, and I am wondering if there is any reason to keep them all? Or to provide them all to other users of the library?

I (so far) understand that I need the bytecode library object `mylibrary.cma` so that I can use mylibrary in the ocaml toplevel as

```
ocaml mylibrary.cma
```

or that I can

```
#load "mylibrary.cma";;
```

from an ocaml script. Then also the compiled interface `mylibrary.cmi`, and the `dllmylibrary.so` (which contains the C parts of the code) are needed for the above to work. And the non compiled interface definition file `mylibrary.mli` is nice to keep for documentation purposes.

But is there any reason to retain also the `mylibrary.cmo` file, if I have the `mylibrary.cma` file? In what kind of case would someone like to have that, too?

EDIT: I mean, I need to construct the `.cmo` in the makefile and then use that to construct the `.cma`, but I was thinking to remove `.cmo` after this, to keep the directory marginally cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, apparently the purpose of different files are (when limiting this to bytecode compiler):

`mylibrary.mli` - human readable interface definition (not strictly needed, compiler only needs .cmi)
`mylibrary.cmi` - compiled interface, needed when compiling code calling mylibrary
`library.o` - C object file
`dlllibrary.so` - shared library object made of the `.o`
`dlllibrary.a` - static library object made of the `.o`
`mylibrary.cmo` - bytecode object compiled from `mylibrary.ml`
`mylibrary.cma` - bytecode library

Then, `mylibrary.cma` (with `mylibrary.cmi` and `dlllibrary.so`) are needed when loading mylibrary from the toplevel:

`#load "mylibrary.cma";;`

OR

One could compile a bytecode program that dynamically links with `mylibrary.cma` (`mylibrary.cmi` and `dlllibrary.so` also needed):

`ocamlc mylibrary.cma <program>.ml`

OR

dynamically linking with bytecode object, instead of the bytecode library (files needed: `mylibrary.cmo`, `mylibrary.cmi`, `dlllibrary.so`):

`ocamlc dlllibrary.so mylibrary.cmo <program>.ml`

(Note: then run the bytecode with: `ocamlrun -I . <program>`, assuming `dlllibrary.so` is in the current directory.)

OR

statically linking with objects (files needed: `mylibrary.cmo`, `mylibrary.cmi` `liblibrary.a`)

`ocamlc -custom liblibrary.a mylibrary.cmo <program>.ml`

OR

statically linking with library objects (files needed: `mylibrary.cma`, `mylibrary.cmi`, `liblibrary.a`)

`ocamlc -custom -I . mylibrary.cma <program>.ml`

So depending on how one is going to use the library in the future, different files are needed. Except `.mli` is only needed for human readers, and the object file`.o` compiled from the C library is not needed (but would be needed when compiling to native code in some cases).

Answer (score 2):

You should even keep the source code of the library. Very often when upgrading the Ocaml compiler (e.g. from 3.12 to future 3.13), you previous `*.cmo` or `*.cma` files won't be able to work without recompilation.

Assuming you can always clean and recompile things (e.g. you have the two traditional targets `clean` and `all` to `make`) you can only keep the `*.cma`

Comment: Yes, of course I will keep the source. I was just thinking, is there any case where somebody would like to use the .cmo instead of the .cma.